# Asterisk wtih OriginateResponse

Tags: asterisk

Someone have used Asterisk with OriginateResponse? How to retrieve the return value of Originate using a php script for example?

Thank's for your help.

Vononka.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to AMI interface

Use actionID when do Originate. Check in response actionid.